# How could I declare all numbers in one if statement I've try declaring all numbers by else if one by one but it seems the code has logical error

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    int quantity;

again:
    cout<<"Enter the quantity: ";
    cin>>quantity;
    If(quantitiy == '1' )
    {
        total = quantity*price
    }
    else
    {
        goto again;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How could I declare all the numbers in one if statement?

Comment: Please help me i really need solution to this problem

Comment: Your question does not even remotely make sense.

Comment: Before anyone can give you a solution, you need to take a [tour] of Stackoverflow, visit the [help], and learn [ask] questions here. Your question is unclear, because you did not follow the rules for posting questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: `quantitiy` is misspelled in `If(quantitiy == '1' )`  and so is `if` (should be lowercase) and `price` and `total` aren't declared at all.

Comment: What is the error to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much everything in your code is wrong and needs fixing.  Use a `do..while` loop instead of `goto`.  Correct your typos on `If` and `quantitiy`.  Declare and initialize the missing `total` and `price` variables.  Add the missing `;` on the `total` assignment. And `'1'` and `1` are two completely different types and values.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    int quantity;
    double price = ...; // for you to decide, unless you ask the user...
    double total = 0;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the quantity: ";
        cin >> quantity;
    }
    while (quantity != 1);

    total = quantity*price;

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, it really doesn't make sense to prompt the user for a quantity and then only accept `1`.  You probably want something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    int quantity;
    double price = ...; // for you to decide, unless you ask the user...
    double total = 0;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the quantity (0 to stop): ";
        cin >> quantity;

        if (quantity == 0) break;

        total += (quantity * price);
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```